# Dynamically created div does not have CSS styles in the DOM in IE8

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-8, dynamically-generated

Using jQuery in IE8, I'm creating a div with a class (ex. `<div class="className"></div>`). This class has several CSS styles on it, including `background`, `margin`, and `border`. When debugging the javascript in IE9 (running as IE8), and inspecting the element, all of the currentStyles have the default values, instead of the values from the CSS. So, when I try to get the `margin`, it comes back as being set to `auto` even though the CSS puts it at `10px`.

The script has no errors and it does work as expected in Firefox, Chrome, and IE9. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds weird can you post the jquery, css and html?

Comment: Does it work if you use the .addClass() after the div is created?

Comment: I've run into jQuery problems with IE8 over the last couple of days actually, so I know how frustrating it can be.  Can you create a jsfiddle so we can play with it?

Comment: I cannot post the js/css/html - I'm working within a .NET application so things are a little complex - and yes, it is weird. The div in question is created like so: `this.$el = $('<div id="{0}" class="portWindow ajaxContainer" style="display: none;"></div>'.format(portWindowId));`

Comment: How is the div generated prior to being inserted into the DOM? is it a string then via innerHtml or is it created via document.createElement()? does the div have any content inside of it? I know IE sometimes self closes what it thinks are "empty" divs which can cause alot of rendering issues (and presumably means styles cant apply to them correctly either)

Comment: @SimonWest Your comments have lead me to take a closer look - it appears that the div is *not* getting inserted into the DOM before I try getting the `margin`. However, for some reason, all of the default DOM properties are available on the element when debugging. Why this works in other browsers, I do not know. I'm not positive this is the problem, but it seems likely at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some help from the comments above (under the original question), I found out that the `div` was not actually in the DOM at the time I was trying to get its CSS properties, which is why I was seeing only the default CSS for the element. Granted, IE9, Firefox, and Chrome all handled this fine, but it does make sense that the element would need to be in the DOM first.

As a workaround, I `append()` a hidden `input` to the DOM, with the same classes as the `div`. I can then get the CSS properties/values that I need and then remove the `input`. While not ideal, this is an acceptable solution for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

There is a refresh button in Developer tools. That reloads the DOM tree without reloading the page.

If you do DOM changes with JavaScript, they are not reflected in the MSIE developer tools, unless you klick the refresh button. See image below:

[image: Refresh Button in MSIE developer tools]

Comment: I doubt this will fix his problem as he specifically states that it works in IE9 and not IE8.